# Divs not floating left and right properly. Stacking oddly

Tags: css, html

Live example here: http://smitecamp.com/

I just want the `.news` div boxes to float left and right using the `cycle` helper in Rails, and here's what I'm currently seeing:

[image]

And here's what I want the layout to actually look like:

[image]

What am I missing here? Why are the divs stacking so oddly?

```
#latestest-news
  .inline-wrapper
    .splitter

    - for news in @news
      .news style="float: #{cycle('left', 'right')};"
        h2
          = link_to news.title, news

        = news.content.html_safe

        .footer
          p by Virtum | #{l news.created_at}
      br
```

Comment: For this layout, you want two column divs, one floated left, and one right, and place your news items in these two columns ( unfloated ). I can't think of a way to do it with your current structure using css alone.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add clear: both to the style declaration, if you want them to stack one on top of the other, however this doesn't get the result you want unless all news divs are of the same height, I would advise you to use masonry http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Adding that `clear: both;` declaration makes the columns be orderedm properly, yes. But there is now an empty space either to the left or right of each box.

Comment: You are right, I think the best way to achieve the result you are looking for is to use masonry

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this if it covers your needs.

[******EXAMPLE******](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/cBFrb/)

What i've done basically is creating two containers named `leftc` and `rightc` inside your `inline-wrapper` div. Also gave your `splitter` a height of 100%.

Hope this helps.